# how to extract the unique values and its count of a column and store in data frame with index key

Tags: pandas, data-science

I am new to pandas.I have a simple question:

how to extract the unique values and its count of a column and store in data frame with index key

I have tried to:

```
df = df1['Genre'].value_counts()
```

and I am getting a series but I don't know how to convert it to data frame object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas series has a [`.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) function. Try it:

```
df = df1['Genre'].value_counts().to_frame()
```

And if you wanna "switch" the rows to columns:

```
df = df1['Genre'].value_counts().to_frame().T
```

---

**Update:** Full example if you want them as columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(400) # To reproduce random variables

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Genre': np.random.choice(['Comedy','Drama','Thriller'], size=10)
})

df = df1['Genre'].value_counts().to_frame().T
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
       Thriller  Comedy  Drama
Genre         5       3      2
```

Comment: yes I have tried it already. But the problem is that i want the value and count as seperate columns

Comment: @maheswaranj How about adding a `.T` to transpose in the end.

Comment: Yea that's exactly what I want thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

try

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df1['Genre'].value_counts())
```

Comment: yes I have tried it already. But the problem is that i want the value and count as seperate columns

Comment: add `reset_index()` and `rename()` should do the job

Comment: `df1['Genre'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "value"})`